# How to redirect a domain to a locale in NextJS?

Tags: redirect, next.js

My NextJS app has two domains:

- ***eldes.com***
- ***eldes.com.br***

I would like that ***eldes.com.br/:path**** to redirects to ***eldes.com/br/:path****

Comment: Have you tried using [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching) to redirect based on the current host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [@juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)'s suggestion, I came up with this solution:

```
{
  source: '/:path*',
  has: [
    {
      type: 'host',
      value: 'eldes.com.br',
    },
  ],
  destination: 'https://eldes.com/br/:path*',
  permanent: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar solution.
Only thing I had to change is that the `type` had to be `header` and then I had to add the `key` value in the header which was `host`.

So in the `next.config.js` it looked something like this:

```
module.exports = withNx({
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [{
          type: 'header',
          key: 'host',
          value: 'fiskeldi.sfs.is'
        }],
        destination: 'https://www.example.com/stuff',
        permanent: true
    }]
  }
})
```